# Is there a convenient way to compare week-over-week data in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a table full of daily aggregate data, but I occasionally need to pull weekly aggregate data, and provide info on increases or decreases.  For that reason, I was considering using T-SQL DATEPART functionality to get week-number and year info for dates.

For example, I can get the following info using today's date (9/11/2020):

```
@nowWeekNumber int = datepart(wk,@today),  --yields 37
@nowYear int = datepart(year,@today),      --yields 2020
```

Using that logic, I could then gather info on records where year is 2020 and weekNumber is 36, and then I could compare those numbers to get a weekly increase/decrease. (Or maybe I'd compare weeks 35 and 36 to ensure that I'm dealing w/ entire weeks, but you get the picture)

However, if the date is 2021-01-03, that's going to return a year of 2021, and a weekNumber of 2.  If I subtract a week, I'm going to get year 2021 and weekNumber 1.  That weekNumber is only going to contain January 1st and 2nd, because 12/27 thru 12/31 are considered year 2020 and weekNumber 53 (even though the calendar week is 12/27 thru 1/2).

In other words, I don't think I can use weekNumber to gather weekly data, even though that would be fairly convenient.  I'm aware that I can use DATEADD functions to grab the start and end-date for consecutive weeks, and I can then gather aggregate data for records BETWEEN those dates, but is there a more-convenient way to do this?

Comment: It's not quite clear from the question what the definition of a week is for the purposes of your reporting. Does the week always start and end on the same day (e.g. Monday), or can it be seven days before/after an arbitrary date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you consider using `dateDiff` as key function? As...

```
select dateDiff(wk, 0, getDate())
```

Returns a single integer for the whole week (**6297** for `'20200911'`) and :

```
select                dateAdd(wk, dateDiff(wk, 0, getDate()), 0),
       dateAdd(dd, 6, dateAdd(wk, dateDiff(wk, 0, getDate()), 0))
```

or

```
select                dateAdd(wk, 6297, 0),
       dateAdd(dd, 6, dateAdd(wk, 6297, 0))
```

gives you the 1st and last day of that week.

Comment: Yes, that's where I'm at right now.  I can manually gather the start and end-dates for a given week.  I just thought it would be more convenient to gather dates where week is xyz, and I can _almost_ do that, except the logic falls apart for the dates around January 1st.  I suppose I could use some of the logic in this answer to grab a group of records where dateDiff(wk,0,dateValue) = a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEPART` but instead of wk you can use the iso week. Then you don't have the problem with a week being split in 2. To be sure also use `SET DATEFIRST` to define exactly on which day the week starts.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1; --use monday as first day of the week
SELECT datepart(iso_week,'2021-01-01');
SELECT datepart(iso_week,'2021-01-03');
SELECT datepart(iso_week,'2021-01-04');
```

The other option is to create your own calendar table and join that to your daily table.

EDIT: for a week start on sunday

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD( DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2020-12-27'),'2020-12-27' ) )
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD( DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2020-12-28'),'2020-12-28' ) )
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD( DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2021-01-01'),'2021-01-01' ) )
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD( DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2021-01-02'),'2021-01-02' ) )
```

Comment: iso_week seems to have the same issue.  1/3/2021 has an iso_week number of 53, but the earlier week of 12/27/2020 thru 1/2/2021 has iso_week values of 52 and 53, respectively.

Comment: Actually it is a different problem.  The DATEFIRST doesn't seems to have effect on the isoweek.  Which makes sense I guess, because it's an international standard.  That's why the iso week always starts on Monday.

Comment: Another option is then to take the week number of the first day of the week (e.g. sunday) for all the days in that week.  Like `DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD( DAY,1 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2020-12-27'),'2020-12-27' ) )`